# closing MYSQL JDBC connection in Spark

Tags: python, mysql, jdbc, apache-spark, pyspark

I am loading data from MYSQL server to Spark through JDBC, but I need to close that connection after loading the data. What is the exact syntax for closing connection?

```
df_mysql = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
  url="jdbc:mysql://***/****”,
  driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
  dbtable="((SELECT jobid, system, FROM Jobs LIMIT 500)  as T)",
  user=“*****”,
  password=“*****”).load()
```

I have tried dbtable.close(). That doesnt work.

Answer (score 9):

There is really nothing to be closed here. `DateFrame` object is not a JDBC connection and `load` doesn't really `load` data. It simply fetches metadata required to build `DataFrame`.

Actual data processing takes place only when you execute a job which contains tasks depending on this particular input and is handled by the corresponding executors. There are responsible for managing connections and fetching data and this process is not exposed to the user.

Comment: Does that mean I need to keep the connection until I process the data? How to close the connection after creating df in spark and before going to expensive computing?

Comment: You don't. This is, or at least should be handled by the input format. Since Spark doesn't load data eagerly and process records in a streaming fashion you can see relatively long living connections. Moreover without caching data may be fetched multiple times and caching itself is much more complex than on plain RDDs.

Comment: I have been getting MYSQL connection time out error when I added time consuming processes in the script. It wasnt there when script was only for loading and doing some simple task on data. That is why I thought of closing connection after creating dataframe.

Comment: I would guess it is some kind of configuration issue but it is unlikely you hit some bug. One way or another manually closing connections with JDBC source is not an option.

Comment: @zero323 What is the suggested reference material to read more about the internal working of spark features? I'm facing a similar issue, the database which my spark job reads from restricts the max concurrent connections per user. The spark `load()` holds on to the connection until the job finishes even though I have only one `load()` call in the beginning of the job and then perform complex transformations on the DF for the reminder of the job.